# Combine two select statments to fetch data from DB

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I am little bit confuse about the problem and I dont know how to respolve this. 
So the problem is following. I have two `Models`(**ReportElement, ReportDefinition**) and one `ViewModel` (**ReportElementDefinitionVM**)

**ReportDefinition Model**

```
public partial class IzvjestajDefinicija
    {
        public IzvjestajDefinicija()
        {
            IzvjestajElementi = new HashSet<IzvjestajElementi>();
            IzvjestajiGenerisani = new HashSet<IzvjestajiGenerisani>();
        }

        public int IzvjestajDefinicijaId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajTipId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajXsdshemaiId { get; set; }
        public string KratkiNaziv { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumUnosa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumAzuriranja { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }

        public virtual IzvjestajTip IzvjestajTip { get; set; }
        public virtual IzvjestajXsdshema IzvjestajXsdshemai { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IzvjestajElementi> IzvjestajElementi { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IzvjestajiGenerisani> IzvjestajiGenerisani { get; set; }
    }
```

**ReportElement Model**

```
public partial class IzvjestajElementi
    {
        public int IzvjestajElementiId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajDefinicijaId { get; set; }
        public string Element { get; set; }
        public string ElementVrijednosti { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumUnosa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumAzuriranja { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }



        public virtual IzvjestajDefinicija IzvjestajDefinicija { get; set; }
    }
```

And ReportElementDefinitionVM

```
public class GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM
    {
        public int IzvjestajiGenerisaniId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajDefinicijaId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajXsdshemaiId { get; set; }
        public string ShemaXSD { get; set; }
        public string KratkiNazivDefinicijeI { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }
        public string Izvjestaj { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumOd { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumDo { get; set; }
        public string ImportedExcel { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumKreiranja { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumUnosa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumAzuriranja { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }
        public string NazivXmlfajla { get; set; }
        public string Elementi { get; set; }
        public string ElementiVrijednosti { get; set; }

    }
```

And right now I have one `Select` statment which take elemnt from `ReportDefinition` and `ReportElementDefinitionVM`

```
 public ListaSveVM UcitajIzvjestaj()
        {
            var listaFromDb = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.Status == 1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId);
            var listaM = new List<GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM>();
            var data = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
                .Select(i => new GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM()
                {
                    IzvjestajiGenerisaniId = i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
                    KratkiNazivDefinicijeI =
                    (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv,
                    Naziv = i.Naziv,
                    Opis = i.Opis,
                    IzvjestajXsdshemaiId = i.IzvjestajXsdshemaiId,
                    ShemaXSD = i.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema,
                }).ToList();


            var lista = "";
            lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
            var listaVM = new ListaSveVM();
            listaVM.sve = lista;
            return listaVM;
        }
```

And Right now, I want to take two property from ReportElement which is (Element,ElementValue) to be display in my `View` and so far I create something like this:

```
 var elementi = _context.IzvjestajElementi.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderBy(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
                .Select(i => new GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM()
                {
                    Elementi = i.Element,
                    ElementiVrijednosti = i.ElementVrijednosti
                }).ToList();
```

And when I pass `elementi` to I get error

`lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);`

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IZ.Model.VM.GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM>' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter'
```

And I also try to create another ViewModel to combine all data from those two models, but I can not fetch data. 
Sorry for long post, but problem is very complicated and I describe problem as better as I can. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem I would be very thankful.

**Update**

**IzvjestajElementi.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IZ.Model.DBModels
{
    public partial class IzvjestajElementi
    {
        public int IzvjestajElementiId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajDefinicijaId { get; set; }
        public string Element { get; set; }
        public string ElementVrijednosti { get; set; }
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumUnosa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatumAzuriranja { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }



        public virtual IzvjestajDefinicija IzvjestajDefinicija { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I want to combine these two into one .Select or redesing these two statment as one

```
var data = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
                .Select(i => new IzvjestajElementiVM()
                {
                    IzvjestajDefinicijaId = i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
                    KratkiNazivDefinicijeI =
                    (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv,
                    Naziv = i.Naziv,
                    Opis = i.Opis,
                    ShemaXSD = i.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema,
                }).ToList();

            var elementi = _context.IzvjestajElementi.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderBy(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
                .Select(i => new IzvjestajElementiVM()
                {
                    Elementi = i.Element,
                    ElementiVrijednosti = i.ElementVrijednosti
                }).ToList();
```

When I pass `element` to

```
lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, elementi);
```

I get error

Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting'

I need something like this

```
var data = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
                .Select(i => new IzvjestajElementiVM()
                {
                    IzvjestajDefinicijaId = i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
                    KratkiNazivDefinicijeI =
                    (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv,
                    Naziv = i.Naziv,
                    Opis = i.Opis,
                    ShemaXSD = i.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema,
                    Elementi = i.Elementi,
                    ElementiVrijednosti = i.ElementiVrijednosti
                });.ToList();
```

I want to display Elementi and ElementiVrijednosti into datatable. Since Elementi and ElementiVrijednosti are not contain in IzvjestajDefinicija only in IzvjestaElementiVM I can not assign. 
So I want to display Elementi and Elementi vrijednosti into my Datatable. Checke picture belowe.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace IZ.Model.VM
{
    public class IzvjestajElementiVM
    {
        public int IzvjestajElementiId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajDefinicijaId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajXsdshemaId { get; set; }
        public int? IzvjestajTipId { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public string Opis { get; set; }
        public string Izvjestaj { get; set; }   
        public byte Status { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikUnosa { get; set; }
        public string KorisnikAzurirao { get; set; }
        public string NazivXmlfajla { get; set; }
        public string ShemaXSD { get; set; }
        public string KratkiNazivDefinicijeI { get; set; }
        public string Elementi { get; set; }
        public string ElementiVrijednosti { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: How does the code in `UcitajIzvjestaj` relate to your issue? Where is `elementi` used in your code?

Comment: I tested the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method, and there are no errors. I think the `UcitajIzvjestaj` method you provided has nothing to do with the `elementi` variable. I hope you can provide your current complete code and tell us the version of the core you are using.

Comment: Sure, what type of code do you need ?

Comment: Elementi is just a Model

Comment: @NetMage I update my code, I added Elementi Model. If you need more code tell me, I will update my question

Comment: @Xerror, I see you have provided the Elementi  model , but what i mean is that the `var elementi` is not related to `UcitajIzvjestaj` method ,right? Did the error happen on this sentence  `var lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(elementi, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);` ?      I hope you give us the complete code  running through the sentence which caused error not the model.

Comment: Yes, I ask for that. `var elementi` I want to insert inside  
var data = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
                .Select(i => new GenerisaniIzvjestajiVM()

Comment: This is the main logic and point of these post.

Comment: I need to combine these two stetment `var elementi` and `var data` int one, but I dont know how. I need to take `Elementi` and `ElementiVrijednosti` from  IzvjestajElementi Model but I dont know how.
`lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);` only accept two parameters

Comment: @YongqingYu I update my question, I hope you understand what I mean right now. If you dont understand please let me know I will  try to explaine a little bit more

Comment: @Xerror，Is your purpose to combine the content of `data` and `elementi`  variables? I don’t know why you put `elementi` in that position? Please explain your needs in detail, and please provide the `IzvjestajElementiVM` model.

Comment: Ok, I will try to update question

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Comment: I update my question @YongqingYu

Comment: Add picture and `IzvjestajElementiVM`

Comment: @Xerror, I have post my answer ,you can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Join()` to combine `_context.IzvjestajElementi` with `data` first.

```
   var data = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
                .Select(i => new IzvjestajElementiVM()
                {
                  IzvjestajDefinicijaId = i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
                  KratkiNazivDefinicijeI = (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv,
                  Naziv = i.Naziv,
                  Opis = i.Opis,
                  ShemaXSD = i.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema,
                }).ToList();

            var elementi = _context.IzvjestajElementi.Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderBy(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId).Join(data,
      post => post.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
      meta => meta.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
      (post, meta) => new { Post = post, Meta = meta })
                .Select(i => new IzvjestajElementiVM()
                {
                    IzvjestajDefinicijaId =  i.Meta.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
                    KratkiNazivDefinicijeI = i.Meta.KratkiNazivDefinicijeI,
                    Naziv = i.Meta.Naziv,
                    Opis = i.Meta.Opis,
                    ShemaXSD = i.Meta.ShemaXSD,
                    Elementi = i.Meta.Elementi,
                    ElementiVrijednosti = i.Meta.ElementiVrijednosti,
                }).ToList();

            var lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(elementi);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am gonna test it right now ! And I will let you know does it works ! :)

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression 'Join<IzvjestajElementi, IzvjestajElementiVM, Nullable<int>, <>f__AnonymousType0<IzvjestajElementi, IzvjestajElementiVM>>(
    outer: OrderBy<IzvjestajElementi, Nullable<int>>(

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to serialise both objects, you could simply combine the two using, for example, [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). ([tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples), [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair?view=netcore-3.1) or any other way would probably work):

```cs
lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {data, elementi});
```

Given two objects both seem to be the same `List<IzvjestajElementiVM>`, you could probably concatenate them together, doing something like this:

```cs
var result = data.Union(elementi); //note, this will work better if you omit .ToList() from data and elementi - linq is lazily invoked
lista = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.ToList());
```

Then, it appears, your models actually linked via navigation properties (and I assume you use EF Core), so you could potentially [`.Include()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) `IzvjestajDefinicija` into second expression:

```cs
var elementi = _context.IzvjestajElementi.Include(e => e.IzvjestajDefinicija).Where(x => x.Status == 1).OrderBy(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
        .Select(i => new IzvjestajElementiVM()
        {
            //report definition properties
            IzvjestajDefinicijaId = i.IzvjestajDefinicija.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
            KratkiNazivDefinicijeI =                    (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv,
            Naziv = i.IzvjestajDefinicija.Naziv,
            Opis = i.IzvjestajDefinicija.Opis,
            ShemaXSD = i.IzvjestajDefinicija.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema,
            // report elements
            Elementi = i.Element,
            ElementiVrijednosti = i.ElementVrijednosti
        }).ToList();
```

I did make a few assumptions, but I'm hoping you'd get the general angle I'm getting at

**UPD**

Given your model relationships, it's very likely you will end up having many `ReportElements` corresponding to one `ReportDefinition`. I can suggest you group by `ReportDefinition`, but how you want to represent the elements - will be up to your specific requirements:

```cs
var elementi = _context.IzvjestajElementi
        .Include(e => e.IzvjestajDefinicija)
        .Where(x => x.Status == 1)
        .GroupBy(g=>g.IzvjestajDefinicija) // group by parent entity, access it through Key property 
        .Select(i => new IzvjestajElementiVM()
        {
            //report definition properties
            IzvjestajDefinicijaId = i.Key.IzvjestajDefinicijaId,
            KratkiNazivDefinicijeI = (_context.IzvjestajDefinicija.Where(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId == i.Key.IzvjestajDefinicijaId && x.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault()).KratkiNaziv,
            Naziv = i.Key.Naziv,
            Opis = i.Key.Opis,
            //ShemaXSD = i.IzvjestajDefinicija.IzvjestajXsdshemai.Shema,
            // report elements
            Elementi = i.FirstOrDefault().Element, // I don't know enough of your code base to be able to project the List<IzvjestajElementi> into anything meaningful here
            ElementiVrijednosti = i.FirstOrDefault().ElementVrijednosti // i is a List<IzvjestajElementi> - it's your call what to do with it here. you probably don't want FirstOrDefault() here - it's just a demo
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.IzvjestajDefinicijaId)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, I am gonna test it right now ! And I will let you know does it works ! :)

Comment: You answer is working correct, but I get duplicate data into DataTable

Comment: probably `IzvjestajElementi` is one to many with `IzvjestajDefinicija`. in this case you might need to somehow group `IzvjestajElementi` by `IzvjestajDefinicija` first

Comment: it's going to be a bit hard to get you exactly what you are after though: one way or another, you will have to somehow deal with the fact that one `IzvjestajDefinicija` has a list of `IzvjestajElementi `. i'll shortly update the example to demonstrate the point, but i don't know enough of your specifics to offer you a drop in solution